# Save the tables in different worksheets on pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this script but I'm getting some issues because the table that I generate is only with one worksheet, I don't know where I can change to have all the worksheets.

The variable columns are the on with the worksheet names

```
for i in columns:
    a=Meios.groupby(['Idade',i]).size().reset_index()
    a["Idade"].replace({1:"18-25", 2:"26-35", 3:">35"}, inplace=True)
    a.columns=['Idade', i, 'Count']
    a.set_index('Idade',inplace=True)

    a.to_excel('aaa.xlsx', 'sheet%s' % i)
```

Comment: Read [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) I'm unsure why your grouping by each column, it doesn't really make sense. better if you provide some sample data

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice, I'm grouping by column to help me out on each information for each column, I didn't put more details about, my main doubt is to create an excel file with different worksheets taking the information for each column, but I'll provide the data on the question

Comment: But thanksss, the link you provide helped me out to write an excel file with different sheets!!!